# Aligning search box to center

Tags: html, css

I picked [a good css/html code](https://designmodo.com/create-drop-down-menu-search-box/) for implementation of search box on the web. But I can't move the search box to center. The below css code is about search box.

```css
#search {
  width: 357px;
  margin: 4px;
}

#search_text{
  width: 297px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  background: #1f7f5c;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<li id="search">
    <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"/>
    </form>
</li>
```

What should I fix the code for aligning the search box?

Thanks.

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: @MehulMohan I added my html code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing `text-align: center` to your `body`.

Refer code:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#search {
  width: 357px;
  margin: 4px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#search_text {
  width: 297px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  background: #1f7f5c;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<li id="search">
  <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" />
    <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button" />
  </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the text in the center of the textbox than use @nashcheez answer.

If you want to align the searchbox itself to the center of the parent than:

1. Set the textbox to display block
2. Give a with to the textbox
3. Set margin-left to auto
4. Set margin-right to auto
5. You may have to set position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use:

```
#search {
  width: 357px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

if its being overridden, try using:

```
#search {
  width: 357px;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `li#search` is all you've got, try this:

```css
#search {
  width: 357px;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

#search_text{
  width: 297px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  background: #1f7f5c;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<li id="search">
    <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"/>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: I added 'auto' at margin line but it doesn't work on my code.

Comment: Then post your complete HTML.